# Making 100's events in one go

Tags: datetime

I am maintaining a calendar for a website where events can be listed in. This year is finishing, which means that soon there will be hundreds of events that need to be put in the calendar for next year. Is there a better way of doing this than manually clicking new page for every event? Ideally I would like to be able to fill a dozen events or so in one go.

Comment: What is the source format of your events? XML, maybe? Or do you have them handed on paper?

Comment: Unfortunately they only exist in a pdf file

Comment: Are events nodes?

Comment: An event is a specific content type that is a date field attached to it. As of now the way to create an event that would show up in the calendar was to make a page from that content type. 

I am not entirely sure if that is the best way to it. I already have hundreds of pages of events resulting in a huge number of page for the site

Comment: Huge number of nodes you can see on sites like http://www.um.warszawa.pl where current NID is about 25'000 (as seen in some of their html sources). I bet you're far from that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your events are nodes, write them into XML or CSV file. Then, you will be able to use [Feeds](https://drupal.org/project/feeds) module to import them in one file upload.

Next time ask the person that makes papers / pdf for you to also send you digital source data she's using.